# CCS Code to remove title header on content box

Tags: css

here is my url [www.hotelchurch.org](http://www.hotelchurch.org).  Above each of my content boxes is a slightly gradient bar that i want to either remove to just make it transparent.  I can enter CSS custom code but can't figure it out and the developer is having trouble too.  Seems like it should be simple to isolate it using the web inspector and then doing some simple CSS... but I'm not succeeding.  Any advice?  thanks.

This was the original code that was given to me by the developer to try. I'm stalled out.  I tried the other suggestions below but nothing

`.otw-sc-contentbox .otw-contentbox-title .otw-regular-title{ background: none !important; }`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how this code was laid out, try going to the elements/box model with the border and typing

```
border-style: hidden;
```

This should just hide the border completely while not collapsing it.

If you cant identify the elements with the border try adding.

```
* {
  border-style: hidden;
}
```

though this will hide ALL the borders on your web page.
:) hope this solves your problem

Comment: I was able to isolate specific rows a one point to ensure min height with this: #otw_grid_manager_content_77 .otw-row:nth-child(2) .contentbox-content {

   min-height: 950px;

}                     but it doesn't seem to be working now.  I tried the codes given above with no luck...